# how to set timeout in rails UJS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs

The new and cool syntax allows me to write:

```
link_to some_path, :remote => true
```

to generate an AJAX request. But if I need longer timeout(e.g. 100000ms), where can I set it? I read [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) but found nothing.

Comment: this ajax request. like `$.ajax( { timeout: 100000, url: some_path })

Answer (score 1):

You can use **$.rails.ajax** property from jquery-ujs, to inject the timeout if it has not been passed explicitly:

```
$(function() {
    // ...

    $.rails.ajax = function(options) {
      if (!options.timeout) {
        options.timeout = 100000;
      }      
      return $.ajax(options);
    };

    // ...
});
```