# How to set timeout using Rails UJS?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, timeout, ruby-on-rails-5, ujs

I am using Rails 5.2.2 and I would like to set a timeout when using Rails UJS so to display an alert message on request timeout.

I read the [Official Guide for working with JavaScript](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) and an [answer related to this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694465/how-to-set-timeout-in-rails-ujs/9386156) but the guide writes nothing about the timeout and the answer is dated.

In my `.html.erb` view file I'm using:

```
<input id="element_dom_id" type="checkbox" data-remote="true" data-url="/a_url" data-params="key=value" data-method="patch">

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('element_dom_id').addEventListener(
    'ajax:success', function(event) {
      ...
    }
  );
  document.getElementById('element_dom_id').addEventListener(
    'ajax:error', function(event) {
      ...
    }
  );
  ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    // ...

    $.rails.ajax = function(options) {
      if (!options.timeout) {
        options.timeout = 100000;
      }      
      return $.ajax(options);
    };

    // ...
});
```

You can use the $.rails.ajax property from jquery-ujs in order to inject the timeout if it hasn't been passed explicitly.

Comment: Where should I insert your code with respect to the code in the question e.g. within the `ajax:before` listener? How/Where the request timeout should be handled e.g. within the `ajax:error` listener? What is the condition to check whether or not to display the alert in case of timeout? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Is there a way to pass explicitly the timeout using Rails UJS?